# Template does not update when using ui-router and ion-tabs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

**CODE**

http://codepen.io/hawkphil/pen/LEBNVB

I have two pages (`link1` and `link2`) from the side menu. Each page has 2 tabs:

`link1`: `tab 1.1` and `tab 1.2`

`link2`: `tab 2.1` and `tab 2.2`

I am using `ion-tabs` for each page to contain the 2 tabs.

This is a very simple design: I want to click on the `link1` or `link2` to go to appropriate route. But for some reason, the state has changed correctly (see Console) but the actual html template did not get updated. **Can you find out what's wrong and how to fix?**

There seems to be some caching problem or something.

**HTML**

```
<title>Tabs Example</title>

<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="link1">
          Link 1
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="link2">
          Link 2
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>

  <ion-side-menu side="right">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm">
      <h1 class="title">Right Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        <a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
          <img src="img/avatar1.jpg">
          <h2>Venkman</h2>
          <p>Back off, man. I'm a scientist.</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>
</ion-side-menus>

<script id="link1.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home">
      <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content has-header="true" has-tabs="true" padding="true">
          <p>Test</p>
          <p>Test Tab 1.1</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>          
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information">
      <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content has-header="true" has-tabs="true" padding="true">
          <p>Test</p>
          <p>Test Tab 1.2</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view> 
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
</script>

<script id="link2.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home">
      <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content has-header="true" has-tabs="true" padding="true">
          <p>Test</p>
          <p>Test Tab 2.1</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>          
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information">
      <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content has-header="true" has-tabs="true" padding="true">
          <p>Test</p>
          <p>Test Tab 2.2</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view> 
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('link1', {
      url: "/link1",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "link1.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('link2', {
      url: "/link2",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "link2.html"
        }
      }
    });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/link1");

})

.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    console.log(toState);
  });

}])
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are currently referring to the latest release which is `1.0.0-rc.0` which has bug while transition from one state to another it is not loading the view.

Further research found that, they had 14 beta releases from version `1.0.0-beta.1` to `1.0.0-beta.14` after they are now on version `1.0.0-rc.0` which is release candidate.

`nav-view` is working perfect till `1.0.0-beta.13` version but it stop working after `1.0.0-beta.14`(which is last beta release),

I would suggest you to degrade your version to `1.0.0-beta.13`, I know depending on beta version is not good thing but still until ionic release stable version you have to rely on it.

**[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYGQZX)** with `1.0.0-beta.13`

**Update:**

Your problem is your view are getting cached because by default caching is enabled inside your ionic app.

Straight from [Ionic Doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/1.0.0-beta.14/api/directive/ionNavView/) (Latest Release doc 1.0.0-beta.14)

> By default, views are cached to improve performance. When a view is
>   navigated away from, its element is left in the DOM, and its scope is
>   disconnected from the $watch cycle. When navigating to a view that is
>   already cached, its scope is then reconnected, and the existing
>   element that was left in the DOM becomes the active view. This also
>   allows for the scroll position of previous views to be maintained.Maximum capacity of caching view is 10.

So by mentioning `cache: false` on `$stateProvider` states function or disabling cache of nav-view globally by doing `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);` inside angular config phase.

So in your case this is what exact problem, your 1st view is getting cache & showing it again & again

There are 3 ways to solve this issue

**1. Disable cache globally**

Disable all caching by setting it to 0, before using it add `$ionicConfigProvider` dependency.

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoeYMe?editors=101)

**2. Disable cache within state provider**

```
$stateProvider
.state('link1', {
  url: "/link1",
  cache: false,
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "link1.html"
    }
  }
})
.state('link2', {
  url: "/link2",
  cache: false,
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "link2.html"
    }
  }
});
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbQaob?editors=101)

**3. Disable cache with an attribute**

```
    <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home">
      <ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="Home">
        <!-- Ion content here -->
      </ion-view>          
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information">
      <ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="Home">
        <!-- Ion content here -->
      </ion-view> 
    </ion-tab>
```

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJymEq)**

I believe the updated approach would be great to implement. Thanks.

Github issue for the same issue [**link here**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3684)

Comment: Oh that is odd... Did someone file a bug with Ionic github?

Comment: @HP.I don't found as such

Comment: @HP. Do check my updated approach, that would be great to implement without any harm. Thanks..

Comment: Had this same problem and solution #1 didn't work for me, had to go with solution #2 on the affected routes. I'd like to thank @pankajparkar once again for helping me found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110598/ionic-app-with-side-menu-and-two-views-with-tabs-dont-switch-correctly/30110723

Comment: By the way I opened this bug on ionic github: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3684