# Ionic app with side-menu and two views with tabs don't switch correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

In my application with a side menu and several pages. One of those pages,  (let's call it Page A) has tabs, everything was working OK - side menu changes the screen with different pages, Page A with tabs had it's tabs working.

Things went south when I tried to add another page with tabs (let's call it Page B). If I am on any page and click on Page A, Page A appears, its tabs works ok. If I click on side menu to open Page B, the URL changes, but nothing happens (Page A is still on screen). All other pages load without problems. If I refresh the browser with Page B URL opened, or refresh on any page other than Page A and then click on Page B side menu link, Page B loads OK, and the reverse happens - any page but Page A will load.

If I comment the code to have tabs on either Page A or Page B, everything works again. So it seems that I can't have an app with side menu and two different pages with different tabs. Is that correct?

Here's my code (relevant parts):

`index.html`:

```
<body ng-app="kinofit">
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

`app.js`:

```
angular.module('kinofit', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.home', {
    url: "/home",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.aerobico', {
    url: "/aerobico",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/aerobico.html",
        controller: 'AerobicoCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.musculacao', {
    url: "/musculacao",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/musculacao.html",
        controller: 'MusculacaoCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

`templates/menu.html`:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/home">
          <i class="icon ion-home"></i> Início
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/aerobico">
          <i class="icon ion-heart"></i> Aeróbico
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/musculacao">
          <i class="icon ion-checkmark-circled"></i> Musculação
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

`templates/musculacao.html`:

```
<ion-view view-title="MUSCULAÇÃO" class="musculacao-view">
  <ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-top" class="tabs-striped">
    <ion-tab title="Tab 1">
      <ion-content class="tabbed-content-within-sidemenu-app padding">
        (...)
      </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Tab 2">
      <ion-content class="tabbed-content-within-sidemenu-app padding">
        (...)
      </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

and `templates/aerobico.html` is the same, changing the view-title and class attributes.

I'm aware that codepen or similar websites would be better to post the code, but I couldn't make it work with multiple html files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like problem related to caching of views, views Caching is by default enable in ionic framework

You need to Disable all caching by setting it to 0, before using it add $ionicConfigProvider dependency.(Do add it in config block)

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

Similar [**answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28932268/2435473)

**OP Edit:** I couldn't get this to work, but adding `cache:false` to the `$stateProvider` call (solution #2 on the "answer here" link above) did the trick for me (OP).

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. When I added ```$ionicConfigProvider``` configuration you suggested, the side many transition from Page A to Page B and vice-versa worked, but the navigation between tabs broked. On Page A, that opens on Tab A1, if I tap on Tab A2 it opens, but if I go back to Tab A1 the page becomes blank. The same happens on Page B.

Comment: @Nighto did you looked at the answer which I have added as link..?

Comment: yes. I'm on ```1.0.0-rc.2```. This is not fixed yet, right? So the solution is still downgrade to ```1.0.0-beta.13```?
What would be the best way to do so, just change ```bower.json``` and then run ```$ bower install```?

Comment: Did the ```bower install``` after editing ```bower.json``` and added ```$ionicConfigProvider``` to the config block, as in: ```[...].config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) { $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0); [...] }```. However I get on console: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxCache' of undefined```. I did a ```console.log($ionicConfigProvider)``` and apparently it has no ```views``` property, only ```$get``` and ```prefetchTemplates```. What I am doing wrong? Thank you once again.

Comment: @Nighto you may have some problem with injection..you should try other option probably the 2nd one will fix your issue

Comment: Also after the downgrade I'm having other errors, such as ```Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ionicHistoryProvider <- $ionicHistory```. I erased the ```lib``` folder and got a fresh copy of ionic and it's dependencies and run ```bower install``` again to be sure that it was not some sort of conflict, but I couldn't get pass this. I think I'll just drop the tabs on one of the pages and find a different solution.

Comment: Going back to ```1.0.0-rc.2``` fixed this last error, by the way. It seems this provider wasn't available on that beta release.

Comment: Believe it or not, on the current ```1.0.0-rc-2``` version, ditching the ```$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);``` and adding ```cache: false``` on the ```$stateProvider``` call did the trick. Thanks a lot for pointing me to this direction, I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: PERFECT ANSWER EVER!!!  I was pulling my hair out in these 2 days to resolve this issue. Thank you @pankajparkar!

Comment: @Nighto really this answer is helping a lots of people who are using `ionic`..Glad to see that.. :)