# Link click does not reload controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app where I want the controller to reload whenever a user visits a tab. I have the following link here...

```
<ion-tab icon-off="ion-ios-person-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-person" ui-sref="tab.profile({reload: true})">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-profile"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

If I visit the tab link once, the controller loads(obviously). If I leave the page and click that same link again the page does not reload. The way I'm detecting this page reload by injecting a `console.log` into the controller file.

```
angular.module('coolsite.user')

.controller('ProfileController', profileController)

profileController.$inject = [];

function profileController(  ) {
  var vm = this;
  console.log("activated");
}
```

How do I reload the controller every time the user clicks on the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `transitionTo` to reload your controller & route.

**Markup**

```
<ion-tab icon-off="ion-ios-person-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-person" ng-click="vm.redirect('tab.profile')">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-profile"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

**Controller**

```
vm.redirect = function(stateName){
   $state.transitionTo(stateName, {} , {
      reload: true,
      inherit: false,
      notify: true
   });
}
```

**Update**

Though it was not related to `angular-ui-router` Its specifically related to `ionic-view`, they getting cached by default. You need can disable those caching  by state just by mentioning `cache: false`.

**Code**

```
.state('tab.profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    views: {
        'tab-profile': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tabs/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController as profile',
            reload: true
        }
    },
    cache: false
})
```

There are also two alternative way to achieve this, you can find it in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28932268/2435473) with better explanation which is given by me only

Comment: Received this `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 3 of the expression [{}, {reload: true}] starting at [, {reload: true}].`

Comment: Is there an issue on line 3 of your code for the controller? I'm trying this with the first argument as a string but still no luck.

Comment: @jason328 are you trying to reload the page? on click of that link

Comment: Still no luck. I've copied this code appropriately, the redirect works but the controller does not reload. I'll post my router code as well.

Comment: I don't want to reload the page per say, but the controller itself. This is important because I want to display a modal if the user is not signed in on visiting that page. So what happens is the user visits the page for the first time, modal pops up, if they visit it again later on then the modal no longer pops up. The modal loads via the controller.

Comment: @jason328 then try `$state.current` instead of `stateName` param in `transitionTo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81793/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-jason328).

Answer (score 1):

So, I think what you're really looking to do is not use the cache.  That means that in your state, you'll want to set `cache: false`.  To be clear, controllers are not "reloaded."  The scope is simple removed and re-added when you return to the page, unless you set the cache to false.

I don't think that's necessarily the best approach though.  I would use the events in the navigation lifecycle and set up a handler for `$ionicView.loaded` instead.  You can find details about the event for [ion-view](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) in the doc under the section: View LifeCycle and Events.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. I'll look into it further.

Comment: @pankajparkar Yup.  Nice answer btw.