# UI-Router: URL changes, but view is not loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I have the following code for my router:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    })
    .state('signup', {
      url: '/signup',
      templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
      controller: 'SignupCtrl'
    })
    .state('userEdit', {
      url: '/user/edit',
      templateUrl: 'templates/user/edit.html',
      controller: 'UserEditCtrl'
    })
    .state('workouts', {
      url: '/workouts',
      templateUrl: 'templates/workouts/index.html',
      controller: 'WorkoutsCtrl'
    })
    .state('workouts.show', {
      url: '/:id',
      templateUrl: 'show.html',
      controller: 'WorkoutCtrl',
      onEnter: function() {
        console.log('this is stupid');
      }
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}])
```

My issue is with the workouts.show state. I have this link:

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="workout in workouts track by workout._id">
  <hr>
  <a ui-sref="workouts.show({id: workout._id})">{{ workout.shortURI }}</a>
  <p>{{ workout.description }}</p>
  <ul class="exercise-list">
    <li ng-repeat="exercise in workout.exercises">{{ exercise }}</li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
</div>
```

When I click on the link with `ui-sref"workouts.show({id: workout._id})"` the url changes to the proper format, and adds the id dynamically, but the view does not load. It just stays on the same page.

I have seen several other questions that are similar, but none of the accepted solutions have worked for me, and I have spent too long on this now.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: looks like caching issue,, you should first try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28932268/2435473

Comment: Does `templates/workouts/index.html` have `ui-view` in it?

Comment: No, @NewDev. It does not. The markup you see above is the whole file. I just want it to display the actual list (index) of the workouts.

Comment: @BenSimmons, well, for a child view to render, the parent must have `ui-view` - otherwise, where would it render?

Comment: @PankajParkar, I added cache:false to the state for workouts.show and it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @NewDev, I changed templates/workouts/index.html to wrap everything in a ui-view div and it works now!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.
You must have a ui-view in your "workouts" state, so that your "workouts.show" will render as a child.
Hope this helps.

Comment: did it help...?