# on create/update, using $state.go('main.myEntries') but until reload the updated or new content doesn't show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I have a page where user can create or update entries.  Then, when user hits 'Submit' the create or update is done and user is sent to the My Entries page.

However, until I reload the page, I am unable to see what I just created or updated.  For example, here is my create:

```
        if(vm.create) {
            Entry.create(vm.entry)
            .success(function(response) {
                vm.saving = false;
                vm.entry = { images : []};
                $state.go('main.myEntries');
            });
```

The user is taken to My Entries page, but only after reloading does the new content show.  How to make it take the user to the My Entries page so that user sees the new content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reload` option here, which value should be true like `{reload: true}` to reload state forcefully.

```
$state.go('main.myEntries', {reload: true});
```

**OR**

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); //reload current state again.
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj I actually tried this after finding another quesiton on the website.  However, it does not seem to work unfortunately :(

Comment: @RamMudaliar which version of `ui-router` you are using? I think it must be old.

Comment: Hello.  I think v0.2.13

Comment: Hello sorry first time I messed up.  I tried the second option.  On clicking submit, it remains at the form entry page.

Comment: @RamMudaliar could you able to reproduce problem in a plunkr?

Comment: Hi Pankaj.  I think i found the issue and it is not with ui-router.  It is caching issue with the ionic... :(

Comment: @RamMudaliar then it must be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28932268/2435473

Comment: @RamMudaliar you could accept the answer..if it does helped.. Thanks :)