# How to reload effectively page in Ionic Framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, reload, page-refresh

I'm developing the mobile application with Ionic framework. The Mobile application has a login page.

After login page , goes to another page which display User's information.Firstly The user log in system, after the user can see own information.But After logout , The another user log  in the system , The another user can't see own information, the user see old user's information.How can I reload the User information's page?

I try to fix the problem such like that ;

While logging out,

```
$scope.Logout=function(){
      AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
      $state.go("app.home",null,{reload:true});
      **$window.location.reload(true);**
      window.localStorage.clear();
    };
```

But it's not effective.

Is there another solution about it ? Could anyone help me about it? 
How can I reload Information page?

I have the same status another section in app ,
The user make a reservation in reservation page, after the user enter another page which name is My Reservation Page,  the user can not see own reservation which already added.

I took a look Ionic view-lifecycle . But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: `$window.location.reload(true);` reloads whole application - make sure to delete old user information *before* it. In this example, place `window.localStorage.clear();` **above** `$window.location.reload()`.

Comment: How can I reload  the specific page ? Not Whole application?

Comment: I think its cache related issue in ionic app, look at this answer to make this workable http://stackoverflow.com/a/28932268/2435473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic cache the page details and information.
To remove that, go to the targeted state in your app.js and add the line of code.

```
cache: false
```

In:

```
.state('tab.aa', {
cache: false,
    url: '/requests',
    views: {
        'tab-aa': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-aa.html',
            controller: 'aaCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

This would force ionic to reload the specific page, in which the controller will pull new information from your webservice. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this doesnt reload the controller.

Comment: @Vandervidi, this force the controller to pull information again from the webservice instead of using cached information