# ionic $state go refresh my view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm using the ionic framework and I want to reload a previously loaded view that has two child view and I want to refresh one of the child.

```
  .state('layout', {
    url: "/layout",
    templateUrl: "templates/layout.html"
  })

    // the pet tab has its own child nav-view and history
  .state('layout.categories', {
    url: '/categories',
    views: {

      // Side Menu
      'side-view': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tickets.html',
        controller: 'ticketsController'
      },

      // Main Content
      'main-view': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/categories.html',
        controller: 'categoriesController'
      }
    }
  })
```

now I have button that when is click I want to go back to the state layout.categories but I want to keep my main-view but I want to refresh the side-view.

```
$scope.cancel = function () {

  $state.go('layout.categories', {}, {reload: true})

};
```

When the page takes me back to the layout.categories state. both views are still part of the DOM.

How do I manage to refresh the side-view ?

Comment: you have destroy and replace that page.

Comment: can you give me more details how can I achieve that.

Comment: If you are modifying side-view somehow and not getting your result then use $ionicHistory.clearCache(); or <ion-view cache-view="false" view-title=" title">
  ....
</ion-view>

Comment: could you look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28932268/2435473 .you might be facing caching related issue.

Comment: on my side-view I have <ion-view="false"> and when I hit the ticketsController is the controller of the side-view I have this.     $scope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", function() {

      $ionicHistory.clearCache();

    });..... none seem to work... only a page reload removed the cache.

Comment: I think you should use $ionicView.afterLeave event.