# HTML contents updates are not showing up in ionic

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, cordova, ionic-framework

We bought an ionFullApp template recently, and I have been trying to edit the HTML content, but the changes are not showing up. 
I have Node.js,cordova and ionic installed and I ran the following command as instructed in the template documentation

```
npm install -g bower
npm install
bower install
ionic setup sass
ionic serve
```

The index page look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; *; style-src  &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; *">
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionic-contrib-tinder-cards/ionic.tdcards.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-slugify/dist/angular-slugify.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/collide/collide.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-contrib-tinder-cards/ionic.tdcards.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-youtube-mb/dist/angular-youtube-embed.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/factories.js"></script>
    <script src="js/views.js"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="your_app_name">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

and one of the view page (workthrough.html) is

```
<ion-view class="walkthrough-view" cache-view="false">
  <ion-content scroll="false">
    <div class="top-content row">
      <div class="col col-center">
        <img ng-src="img/logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-content row">
      <div class="col col-center">
        <a class="login button button-block button-stable" ui-sref="auth.login">
          Log In 
        </a>
        <a class="sign-up button button-block button-stable" ui-sref="auth.signup">
          Sign Up
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Yet I made some  HTML changes in the  view directory and it's not updating . Is there something I am getting wrong?

Please help any body.
Thanks

Comment: The "view" directory... could be specific of the template you are using. Default basic templates starters has a directory named "templates" for html views. Try: `ionic serve --consolelogs --serverlogs --all` - when you edit a file it should print a line about the changes.

Comment: it's showing in the log (git bash log) that changes were made to certain files , but it's not updating on the interface

Comment: And if you refresh manually you see the changes, right? What browser are you using? What OS?

Comment: yes, my own view is equivalent to the template of the basic starter, Image Changes are showing up, only the HTML content in the views are not showing

Comment: No, even manually, it's not showing

Comment: I am on windows 10 and I have tried it on chrome and Firefox

Comment: Try to post some code (index, views, etc.)

Comment: I have posted some codes

Comment: A friend said something about template cache as the cause, do you know how I could deal with that?

Comment: I'm having this problem too on Windows 10 from a purchased template. I implemented the cache directives defined in this SO answer but changes in my html files are still not showing up.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28932268

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue with ionFullApp. This is a real hardcoded template caching used by the ionFullApp. 
Follow these steps to remove caching

1. Look for gulp-tasks folder. Open default.js. Comment out the following line

   ```
   gulp.watch(paths.templatecache, ['templatecache']);
   ```
2. Go to ionic.project file in home menu and comment this

   ```
   "templatecache",
   ```
3. Inside www/js folder, open views.js and comment it all out
4. Open app.js. Find `'your_app_name.views',` in the dependencies list and comment it out.
5. Go to index.html and comment out the reference to 'views.js' (just to be safe)
6. If you have used any other un-caching commands like

   ```
   $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
   ```

   remove it.

Your templates should now edit as per your commands. This is probably some error in the gulp task, otherwise it should cache your changes between views, and not the original templates.