# Angular Ionic UI-Router - how to ensure all the parent views are loaded when starting the app in a nested state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

I have an `ui-router` structure:

```
    .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'menu.html',
    })

    .state('app.parent', {
      url: '/parent',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'parent.html',
        }
      }
    })    

    .state('app.parent.next', {
      url: '/next',
      views : {
        'next' : {
          templateUrl: 'next.html'
        }
      } 
    })
```

`parent.html` contains `ui-view` and link to the `app.parent.next`

```
<ion-view view-title="Parent">

  <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
    <button class="button" ng-click="$state.go('app.parent.next')">
      next »
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-content has-header="true">
    <h1>Parent</h1>

    <div ui-view></div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

It works just fine, however if I start the app directly in `app.parent.next` state the header and template are not there.

- http://michalstefanow.com/ionic.html#/app/parent - works just fine
- http://michalstefanow.com/ionic.html#/app/parent/next - `next` nested-view is loaded, it's just the `ion-nav-buttons` defined in the parent are not there

**(provided link to hosted version because to reproduce it is essential to start in a nested state)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link data-require="ionic@1.2.4" data-semver="1.2.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" />
    <script data-require="ionic@1.2.4" data-semver="1.2.4" src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script>
      angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

      .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

        .state('app', {
          url: '/app',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: 'menu.html',
        })

        .state('app.parent', {
          url: '/parent',
          views: {
            'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: 'parent.html',
            }
          }
        })    

        .state('app.parent.next', {
          url: '/next',
          views : {
            'next' : {
              templateUrl: 'next.html'
            }
          } 
        })

        // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/parent');
      })      
    </script>
    
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="menu.html">

      <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
        <ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-nav-bar style="background-color: transparent !important;">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
              <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
              </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
          </ion-nav-bar>
          <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>

        <ion-side-menu side="left">
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
            <ion-list>

              <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/parent">
                Parent
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/parent/next">
                Directly into next
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
      </ion-side-menus>

    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="parent.html">

      <ion-view view-title="Parent">
        
        <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
          <button class="button" ui-sref='app.parent.next'>next »</button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        
        <ion-content has-header="true">
          <h1>Parent</h1>
          <h1>Parent</h1>
          <h1>Parent</h1>
          
          <div ui-view="next"></div>

        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>

    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="next.html">

      <h1>Next</h1>
      <h1>Next</h1>
      <h1>Next</h1>

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried something similar with pure `ui-router` implementation:

- http://michalstefanow.com/ui-router.html#/app/parent
- http://michalstefanow.com/ui-router.html#/app/parent/child

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>UI Router</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script>
     
      angular.module('starter', ['ui.router'])

      .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

        .state('app', {
          url: '/app',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: 'main.html',
        })

        .state('app.parent', {
          url: '/parent',
          views: {
            'main': {
              templateUrl: 'parent.html',
            }
          }
        })    

        .state('app.parent.child', {
          url: '/child',
          templateUrl: 'child.html'
        })

        // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/parent');
      });
    </script>
    
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <div ui-view></div>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
      <h1>This is main.html</h1>

      Below is:
      <pre>ui-view="main"</pre>
      <div ui-view="main"></div>
    </script>    

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="parent.html">
      <h1>Parent</h1>
          
      <a ui-sref="app.parent.child">child »</a>

      <div ui-view></div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="child.html">
      <h1>I am a child</h1>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Speculation guesstimate: something`Ionic` specific due to caching - [Template does not update when using ui-router and ion-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827928/template-does-not-update-when-using-ui-router-and-ion-tabs) ?

---

What am I really trying to do? Just to avoid XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - I want guide a user to upload an image. There will be couple of steps and the user will land directly in state `app.upload.one` without touching `app.upload` directly. `app.upload` will keep the current state of the upload process, while each of the steps will add description, tags, etc...

Comment: Why don't you force the app to allways start in the app.parent state? $location.path("/parent"); in your run block for example.

Comment: @user3791775 - not forcing my app to start in ```app.parent``` because it may start in ```app.grandfather``` or maybe even ```app.santaclaus```

Answer (score 1):

I think that ionic is single page application,so there is just one parent (which is root,like `tabs` or `menu`),others all are the child,and specially important is that the others are all siblings,so they can't be the relation of parent and child.
In short,you only can use one dot notation like  `app.child` , don't like `app.child.grandchild` which has two dot notations.

Comment: Can you please provide any source, reference, documentation to that?

Comment: In  fact there is no source or documentation,That's just how I understand it.I think that you need understand  single page application ,  and [Nested Views]( https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)  that will help you.